# REST API - Server to server connection via API key / permanent token?

Tags: rest-api, authentication

I am looking to set up a connection from our website, to populate leads, and am struggling to find the right authentication method.

Previously (using a different CRM), we simply POSTed a json payload to a specific endpoint (/api/leads) with an auth token header. The token was generated via the CRM admin panel, and valid until revoked, so was simply 'hard coded' into the app (actually using environment variables).

```
curl 
    -H "Authorization: Token token=sfg999666t673t7t82" 
    -H "Content-Type: application/json" 
    -d '{"lead":{"first_name":"Eric", "last_name":"Sampleton", "mobile_number":"1-926-652-9503"}' 
    -X POST "https://domain.freshsales.io/api/leads"
```

I cant seem to find anything similar for Salesforce though. Since this is automated, OAuth doesnt seem suitable. Web-to-lead appears to be outdated, and doesnt provide a response, so we cant access the salesforce lead id, and I have no intention of even looking at SOAP docs!

Is a similar flow available for salesforce (permentant token / API key), and if not, what is the simplest alternative

Comment: The simplest alternative would be OAuth JWT Bearer Flow (authorisation via a private key and certificate) -- great example is here https://blog.deadlypenguin.com/2019/03/08/jwt-bearer-auth-salesforce-node/.
Completely automated and secure